# Getting property value from model in view using Razor without new object declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, entity

Let's say I have the following view:

```
@model CityViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.City.Name) @* This is fine *@

Welcome to @Model.City.Name @* This will error *@
```

I get the following error on the @Model.City.Name : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

How do I go about grabbing the value directly from the views model?...

**------------ Please note that there is more to this than CityViewModel, it's just I've stripped out the sensitive names -----------------**

My CityViewModel has a mixture of City, State, Country type... they are simply properties of that type inside the ViewModel:

```
public class CityViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public City City;

    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public Country Country;
}
```

and then I fetch this stuff with a Linq join and return a CityViewModel with it:

```
    public CityViewModel CVMGetByID(int cityID)
    {
        var cityViewModel =
            from _ in context._
            join address in context.Addresses on _.AddressID equals address.AddressID
            join city in context.Cities on address.CityID equals city.CityID
            join country in context.Countries on address.CountryID equals country.CountryID
            join state in context.States on address.StateID equals state.StateID
            where _._ID == _ID
            select new CityViewModel ();

        return cityViewModel.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Also check if you are even sending your data to your view from the controller as well. Like this maybe `return View(new CityViewModel{...});`

Comment: I think issue is you are not passing model from controller to view

Comment: I think you're right... my linq may be failing to retrieve anything... now that makes sense.. ill keep you updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe assign the Data from your query.
Something like

```
...
select new CityViewModel {
City = _City;
};
```

and so on.

Comment: YEHAAAA, I lovee youuuuu!!!! that was the bastard right there.. YOOOOOOP... I want your babies, my friend.. Guess whos the newbie here :)

Comment: I'm pleased i can help you. However, i'm feeling like a newbie cause i can't comment. ;)
One more hint, this is closely related to linq / entity framework. Take into conideration to add another tag.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you're using fields in your view model and not properties. Perhaps that changing:

```
public City City;
```

to

```
public City City { get; set; }
```

will fix your issue.

Comment: Oh DUHHH, good spot man! ill keep you updated if that was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass just one Object to the View or a List of Objects? 
In case of a list try:

```
@Model.City[0].Name
```